# Does undefined behavior only concern an execution of program, or can it concern a program itself?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I'm trying to clarify my understanding of what undefined behavior is in a more formal, rigorous manner, especially in the context of the C++ standard.

The following quote to me from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub, seems incorrect:

> Because correct C++ programs are free of undefined behavior, compilers
> may produce unexpected results when a program that actually has UB is
> compiled with optimization enabled:

To me it does not generally make sense to say that a program itself is/is not free of undefined behavior - it only ever makes sense to me to talk about undefined behavior in the context of a particular execution of the program. For the same program, execution with one input might end up using some operation that is not properly defined (and thus the execution of the program has undefined behavior), for some other input it might not. Sometimes it can be determined that the program execution will/will not produce undefined behavior for every input, but that's generally not the case.

It also seems to be in conflict with the following from the standard:
https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#intro.abstract-5

> A conforming implementation executing a well-formed program shall
> produce the same observable behavior as one of the possible executions
> of the corresponding instance of the abstract machine with the same
> program and the same input. However, if any such execution contains an
> undefined operation, this document places no requirement on the
> implementation executing that program with that input (not even with
> regard to operations preceding the first undefined operation).

Is the cppreference quote wrong, or is there some sense in which a "program" itself, not its execution, can have undefined behavior?

Comment: No UB is not restricted to a particular execution. Your program either has it or does not have it. You might just get lucky (in the bad sense of the word) that the UB part is not called. It still is not a correct program.

Comment: Please, consider that if code exhibits Undefined Behavior the compiler is free to generate any output for that and other code of the concerned translation unit. (E.g. it may make wrong assumptions about possible optimizations.)

Comment: See [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) for how UB can affect other parts of the code, even before it is reached.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Of course it can be restricted to a particular execution, if it depends on user input.

Comment: Why is this important? How does the answer one way or another affect anything?

Comment: *"Sometimes it can be determined that the program execution will/will not produce undefined behavior for every input, but that's generally not the case."* -- I find this an unconvincing argument. This merely implies *"Sometimes it can be determined that **a program is correct**, but that's generally not the case."* and there is no need to determine if a program is correct in order for the cppreference.com quote to apply. (In fact, sometimes it is an unexpected result with optimizations enabled that reveals that the program is not correct.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ofcourse it will exhibit only for certain inputs, that's not my point...  So when is the last time you trusted user input? ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer "All/some/none of the executions of the program exhibit UB" are properties of the program, however they are generally unverifiable and the C++ standard cannot say when a program has/does not have these properties. (Except for cases when an answer can be given by static analysis of program text alone, e.g. [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex#phases-1.2)). In most cases the standard can only say "if the program executes this construct (such as division by zero), then the behaviour is undefined".

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit Fair enough. Proving a program has UB is next to impossible.

Comment: @PepijnKramer So why is "a program has UB" a useful proposition then? Why do we discuss it?

Comment: I would advice reading the very good articles referenced at the end of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Undefined behavior is a property of a program. Generally:

- programs have behavior
- executions of programs have effects

> ###### 3.65 undefined behavior [[defns.undefined]](https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined)
>
> behavior for which this document imposes no requirements
>
> *[- Note 1:* Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving **during translation or program execution** in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a **diagnostic message**), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message). [...] *- end note]*

When the standard refers to a *program* having undefined behavior, it refers to the program generated by the compiler.
Undefined behavior can be handled during *translation* (i.e. compilation) too, as said in the quote above.

For example, a division by zero is encoded in that program, and that division by zero has an undefined effect, once it is executed.
When handled during *translation*, you can tell whether a program contains undefined behavior, even without executing it:

```cpp
int main() {
    return 1 / 0;
}
```

GCC with `-O2` compiles this to:

```
main:
        ud2
```

... with the *diagnostic message*:

```
warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
    2 |     return 1 / 0;
      |            ~~^~~
```

> #### `ud2`
>
> Generates an invalid opcode exception. This instruction is provided for software testing to explicitly generate an invalid opcode exception. The opcodes for this instruction are reserved for this purpose.

- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ud

However, there are many cases where undefined behavior takes place only for some program input, and you wouldn't see `ud2` in the assembly output.
In such a case, the program *has undefined behavior* for said input, but the undefined behavior only takes effect if you execute it with said input.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the concept of the "behavior of a program" to begin with. Is it the behavior of the program to a particular input? Is it a quality that concerns all possible executions of the program? To me, it makes sense to talk about the behavior of the program with respect to some input, i.e. a particular execution of the program, but otherwise, I'm not completely sure. What would be a proper definition of the "behavior of a program" ?

Comment: Also, if I understand it correctly, this means that as soon as there is any sort of undefined behavior (even if it only happens for a particular input), this means "the program has undefined behavior".

Is this not a conflict with the as-if rule as stated here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if "Programs with undefined behavior,..., are free from the as-if rule, they often change observable behavior...".

Should this not mean that as soon as there exists any sort of UB (even if it can't be reached), it's perfectly valid for the program to do nothing?

Comment: @JohnP the behavior of the program is the the output, given some input. As the term "behavior" suggests, it's "what the program does". For example, the behavior might be that it reads an integer from `stdin`, multiplies it with two, and prints that out. The standard doesn't define what "behavior" is, it's a common term that people can look up in a dictionary.

Comment: @JohnP no, it's not possible to make program do nothing if there is any UB in it. Any output of the program up until the point of undefined behavior still has to happen. However, whatever the program does at the point of undefined behavior (i.e. what happens when an execution runs into an undefined operation) is unclear; there are no limits.

Comment: @JanSchultke I'm not sure your second comment is correct - assuming the compiler can deduce that this is UB: `void f(){ std::cout << "qwe"; int* p = nullptr; int q = *p;}`, I have assumed it is perfectly acceptable for `f` to simply get compiled to do nothing (and calls to `f` can be replaced by nothing). Is this not true? Does it not conflict with what you have said?

Comment: @JohnP Printing `qwe` is still an observable side effect of the program, and needs to happen. The behavior of the program is perfectly well-defined until the null pointers gets dereferenced, and the string should be printed. The following dereferencing of a null pointers gets treated like a `std::unreachable()` hint. See https://godbolt.org/z/3q6GMc8W1. Also note that `std::unreachable()` is literally just a function that invokes UB. However, calling it doesn't make the whole program invalid, it just tells the compiler that it's UB *once* execution reaches it.

Comment: @JanSchultke Are you sure about this? I think it would be valid for a compiler to compile `f` to nothing, based on the quote in my original post: "if any such execution contains an undefined operation, this document places no requirement on the implementation executing that program with that input (not even with regard to operations preceding the first undefined operation)."

Comment: @JohnP the problem is that in practice, any form of I/O can throw, and the program can also be terminated by a signal handler before reaching UB. There are many reasons why even though the program contains unconditional UB at some point, the execution never reaches that point. But yes, if the compiler can prove (through whole-program analysis and other insane means) that the UB is always reached, then the preceding code can also be assumed UB. It's just not really possible to do that in most cases.

Comment: You can see that no compiler does this, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/Yc73z4Gvd; so observable side effects are treated as something that *must* happen. After all, a `volatile` write to mapped memory could result in other consequences that allows us to not reach the `__builtin_unreachable()` here.

Comment: @JanSchultke Right, I know this is an edge case, and practice might differ. This is all in the theoretical context of what the standard imposes. My issue is that the quote "Programs with undefined behavior,..., are free from the as-if rule" makes it sound that as soon a program has any sort of undefined behavior (regardless of whether it is unconditionally reached), anything goes for the whole program, which conflicts with https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#intro.abstract-5. "Programs with unconditional undefined behavior,..., are free from the as-if rule" would be correct. Do you agree?

Comment: @JohnP yes, I would agree.